# Sqs error in which Approximate age pf oldest alarm is high

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops, amazon-sqs

I am having sqs with visibility time out of 30 minutes and we have setup sqs approximate age of oldest message alarm for value 14000 for 1 data point within 1 minute, the alarm is going high everytime and this issue is recurring and i am not sure what to be done. Any suggestions that i can follow. Its default retention period is 1 day. Thanks

Comment: Do you have errors in your consumer and the message is retried / redriven multiple times and therefore is actually reaching that age?